# unable to create docker container for tensorflow serving

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, tensorflow-serving, docker-container

I am trying to create a tensorflow serving docker container but I am getting the following error while running the docker create command[image]

I am unable to figure out if its because of any location error or my /bin/bash file is broken. What can I do to fix this issue ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What base image are you using?

Answer (score 1):

What base image are you using for your container image? I checked busybox and alpine. They have `ash` by default but not `bash`. Once you create your image you can run it as follows:
`docker run -it my-image-name "sh"`
This should get you into an interactive shell. The `cd` into `/bin` and check which commands are available using `ls`.

I got this in alpine

```
/ # ls /bin
ash            df             getopt         linux64        mpstat         rev            sync
base64         dmesg          grep           ln             mv             rm             tar
bbconfig       dnsdomainname  gunzip         login          netstat        rmdir          touch
busybox        dumpkmap       gzip           ls             nice           run-parts      true
cat            echo           hostname       lzop           pidof          sed            umount
chgrp          ed             ionice         makemime       ping           setpriv        uname
chmod          egrep          iostat         mkdir          ping6          setserial      usleep
chown          false          ipcalc         mknod          pipe_progress  sh             watch
conspy         fatattr        kbd_mode       mktemp         printenv       sleep          zcat
cp             fdflush        kill           more           ps             stat
date           fgrep          link           mount          pwd            stty
dd             fsync          linux32        mountpoint     reformime      su
```

A container is an instance created from a container-image. In your case your container `tf_container_gpu` has been created from the image you specified. You can give your container a name only the time you create it. After that you just need to start it with that name.

`docker start tf_container_gpu` should do.

if you want to recreate your container (say after you re-build your image) first remove the earlier container instance

`docker container rm tf_container_gpu`. Then run the container again

`docker run --name=tf_container_gpu <image-name>`

To just start and stop the container
`docker start tf_container_gpu`
`docker stop tf_container_gpu`